# Insert with Select causes "Subquery returned more than 1 value" eventhough subqueries return expected values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-insert

Using MS Sql Server 2008 I'm trying to insert multiple rows into a users_roles table using the fancy Insert/Select syntax. When executing this query, I get the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Both subqueries, when executed on their own, return the expected values. Multiple records in the first subquery and a single record in the second.

```
insert into users_roles(userid, roleid)
        select 
            (select distinct users.id as userID from users 
                inner join users_roles on users.id = users_roles.userid 
                inner join roles on users_roles.roleid = roles.id
                where roles.projectid = 1)
            , 
            (select id as roleID from roles where projectid = 1 and name = 'ALL')
```

What am I missing out here?

Comment: So you want something like row 1 (multiple values, 1 value) it is not possible. You need to rethink your query and avoid fixing using `TOP 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not even know if the second (or first) will return 0, 1, or many

```
decalare @roleID int;
set @roleID = (select top 1 id from roles where projectid = 1 and name = 'ALL');
insert into users_roles(userid, roleid)
select distinct users.id as userID, @roleID 
from users 
inner join users_roles on users.id = users_roles.userid 
inner join roles on users_roles.roleid = roles.id
where roles.projectid = 1;
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you @Frisbee

Comment: @CDC News flash.  "SQL does not even know if the second (or first) will return 0, 1, or many"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax to insert multiple records or a single record, but not at the same time! As it stands, your query is trying to select multiple values in the first column, and a single value in the second.

You don't need two subqueries. Just make your first subquery into the outer query (returning multiple rows), and your second subquery will then return a single row for each:

```
insert into users_roles(userid, roleid)
    select distinct users.id as userID,
           (select id as roleID from roles where projectid = 1 and name = 'ALL') as roleID
            from users 
            inner join users_roles on users.id = users_roles.userid 
            inner join roles on users_roles.roleid = roles.id
            where roles.projectid = 1)
```

Note that you don't really need the column aliases, they're just there for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

It is the multiple rows in the first subquery that is causing the issue. You have it as a column the way you built this. If it returns multiple rows sql doesn't know which row you want.

Something like this is probably what you are looking for.

```
select distinct users.id as userID from users 
inner join users_roles on users.id = users_roles.userid 
inner join roles on users_roles.roleid = roles.id
cross apply 
(
    select id as roleID from roles where projectid = 1 and name = 'ALL'
)
where roles.projectid = 1
```